# Split parent pane instead of the active one

Tags: tmux

Let's say I've obtained this configuration by using `splitw -h` once, with `A` currently active:

```
+---+---+
| A | B |
|   |   |
|   |   |
+---+---+
```

How can I add a new split *below* those 2 splits?

```
+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+---+
|   C   |
+---+---+
```

I'm not sure how to search for this... Everything I've found is about splitting *inside* a pane with `splitw`, which is not what I want:

```
+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+   |
| C |   |
+---+---+
```

*For those familiar with [i3](http://i3wm.org), this would be the equivalent of sending `focus parent; split v` before opening the new window.*

Is `tmux` able to do this? I'd rather stop searching now if that's not the case :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `split-window -f` command.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried cycling through layouts? I managed to get the layout you are aiming for by splitting into three panes and then cycling through the layouts. Default keybinding for cycling through layouts is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

Comment: I should've mentionned that's what I currently do, but trying every possibilities until finding the good one is a workaround, not a solution ;)